# Unable to fetch value from gui tkinter text box

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

**_Recommendation_by_food.py**

```
'''

Created on Feb 24, 2018

@author: Harshit Sinha
'''
import pandas as pd
import os
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import _tkinter
from pygments.lexers._vim_builtins import command

#from _MainScreen import B1

win = tk.Tk()
#win.update()
win.title("RECOMMENDER SYSTEM FOR FOODS")
win.geometry('500x500')


#name = StringVar()
'''
id = tk.StringVar()
Food1 = tk.StringVar()
Food1_rating = tk.StringVar()
'''

class initialize_screen(tk.Tk):
##################user inputs


    ## User_name
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    def _draw_screen(self):
        self.User_Name_Label=tk.Label(self,text="User Name :").grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.name = tk.StringVar()
        Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.name).grid(column=1, row=0)


        ## User_id
        self.User_id_Label=tk.Label(self, text="User id :").grid(column=0, row=1)


        self.id = tk.StringVar()
        self.User_id_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.id).grid(column=1, row=1)

        ## Food1
        self.Food1_Label=tk.Label(self, text="Food1 :").grid(column=0, row=2)


        self.Food1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food1_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.Food1).grid(column=1, row=2)

        ## Food1_rating
        self.Food1_rating_Label=tk.Label(self, text="Rating :").grid(column=2, row=2)


        self.Food1_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food1_rating_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.Food1_rating).grid(column=3, row=2)

        ## Food2
        self.Food2_Label=tk.Label(self, text="Food2 :").grid(column=0, row=3)


        Food2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food2_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=Food2).grid(column=1, row=3)

         ## Food2_rating
        self.Food2_rating_Label=tk.Label(self, text="Rating :").grid(column=2, row=3)


        self.Food2_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food2_rating_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.Food2_rating).grid(column=3, row=3)


        ## Food3
        self.Food3_Label=tk.Label(self,text="Food3 :").grid(column=0, row=4)


        self.Food3 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food3_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.Food3).grid(column=1, row=4)


         ## Food3_rating
        self.Food3_rating_Label=tk.Label(self, text="Rating :").grid(column=2, row=4)


        self.Food3_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food3_rating_Input=tk.Entry(self,width=12,textvariable=self.Food3_rating).grid(column=3, row=4)


        ##submit button
        self.submit = Button(self, text="Submit",command=self.print_val).grid(column=0,row=5)

        ##reset button
        self.reset = tk.Button(self, text="Reset").grid(column=1, row=5)

#        win.resizable(0, 0)
#        self.User_Name_Input.focus()
#        win.mainloop()
        print(self.name.get())


    def print_val(self):
#        global name,id,Food1,Food1_rating

        print('hi')
        name1 = self.name.get()
        print(str(name1))
#        print(self.Food1.get())
#        print(self.Food1_rating.get())
#        print(self.Food2_Input.get())
#        print(self.Food2_rating_Input.get())
#        print(self.Food3_Input.get())
#        print(self.Food3_rating_Input.get())
```

**_MainScreen.py**

```
'''
Created on Feb 24, 2018

@author: Harshit Sinha
'''
import pandas as pd
import os
import Tkinter as tk
import _tkinter


#bring up MainScreen
import _Recommendation_by_food as fd
from _Recommendation_by_food import *


def call_screen_1():
    fd=initialize_screen()
    fd._draw_screen()
#    fd.__init__()

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

B1 = tk.Button(win,text ="Recommendation By Food",width=30, command=call_screen_1)
#B2 = tk.Button(win,text ="Recommendation By Ingredients",width=30,command= call_screen_2)
#B3 = tk.Button(win,text ="Recommendation By Nutrition",width=30,command= call_screen_3)

B1.pack()
#B2.pack()
#B3.pack()

#win.resizable(0, 0)

win.mainloop()
```

I'm doing a POC on machine learning using python and stuck on an issue.
I'm using `tkinter` library for developing gui as you can see i have given two code snippets above

1. `_MainScreen.py`
2. `_Recommendation_by_food.py`

When the program is executed it calls `_MainScreen.py` which has buttons, so if user select one option, say "Recommendation by food", it will open another window and contain relevant text boxes for input, once user provides the value and clicks on submit button, the value should appear in screen, which is not happening though.

Comment: One significant problem is when you do things like `self.User_Name_Label=tk.Label(self,text="User Name :").grid(column=0, row=0)`, you end up assigning `None` to the `self.User_Name_Label` attribute because `grid()` doesn't return a value. You should split all of these into into two separate statements.

Comment: hi martineau , i'm trying to extract value from variable "name'' which is of type StringVar, and second, the extraction logic is written in function, so chances are there that correct reference is not passed.Since I'm new to Tkinter can you help me with the correct code snippet

Comment: Describe what "not happening" means. Is it throwing an error? Is it returning the wrong value? Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. It will help you to better understand the problem, and also help you describe the problem to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't remember all the changes I made to get your code working, the major ones that I do recall were to remove all the modules and code that aren't being used and made it follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) more closely (not completely).

Another major modification was to ***not*** derive your `initialize_screen` (renamed `InitializeScreen`) class from `tk.TK`, and have it instead call `tk.Toplevel()` to create a second window separate from the main one. Related to that I moved the call to `tk.Tk()` into the main script.

Here's versions of the two scripts which I think together show how to do what you said you were trying to accomplish:

**_Recommendation_by_food.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk

class InitializeScreen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Toplevel(takefocus=True)  # Create a new window.

    def draw_screen(self):
        ## User_Name
        self.User_Name_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="User Name :")
        self.User_Name_Label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.User_Name = tk.StringVar()
        self.Name_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.User_Name)
        self.Name_Input.grid(column=1, row=0)

        ## User_id
        self.User_id_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="User id :")
        self.User_id_Label.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.id = tk.StringVar()
        self.User_id_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.id)
        self.User_id_Input.grid(column=1, row=1)

        ## Food1
        self.Food1_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Food1 :")
        self.Food1_Label.grid(column=0, row=2)
        self.Food1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food1_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.Food1)
        self.Food1_Input.grid(column=1, row=2)

        ## Food1_rating
        self.Food1_rating_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Rating :")
        self.Food1_rating_Label.grid(column=2, row=2)
        self.Food1_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food1_rating_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.Food1_rating)
        self.Food1_rating_Input.grid(column=3, row=2)

        ## Food2
        self.Food2_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Food2 :")
        self.Food2_Label.grid(column=0, row=3)
        Food2 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food2_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=Food2)
        self.Food2_Input.grid(column=1, row=3)

        ## Food2_rating
        self.Food2_rating_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Rating :")
        self.Food2_rating_Label.grid(column=2, row=3)
        self.Food2_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food2_rating_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.Food2_rating)
        self.Food2_rating_Input.grid(column=3, row=3)

        ## Food3
        self.Food3_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Food3 :")
        self.Food3_Label.grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.Food3 = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food3_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.Food3)
        self.Food3_Input.grid(column=1, row=4)

        ## Food3_rating
        self.Food3_rating_Label = tk.Label(self.win, text="Rating :")
        self.Food3_rating_Label.grid(column=2, row=4)
        self.Food3_rating = tk.StringVar()
        self.Food3_rating_Input = tk.Entry(self.win, width=12, textvariable=self.Food3_rating)
        self.Food3_rating_Input.grid(column=3, row=4)

        ## Submit button
        self.submit = tk.Button(self.win, text="Submit", command=self.print_val)
        self.submit.grid(column=0,row=5)

        ## Reset button
        self.reset = tk.Button(self.win, text="Reset")
        self.reset.grid(column=1, row=5)


    def print_val(self):
        name1 = self.User_Name.get()
        print('name1: {!r}'.format(name1))
```

**_MainScreen.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk
from _Recommendation_by_food import InitializeScreen

def call_screen_1():
    fd = InitializeScreen()
    fd.draw_screen()

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Recommender System For Foods')
win.geometry('500x500')

B1 = tk.Button(win, text="Recommendation By Food", width=30, command=call_screen_1)
B1.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @martineau, your code really helped me to proceed with my work, a ton of thanks for you :-) :-)